# How to get users information that liked each other using Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-relations

I have a query below that checks if the users like each other:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.target_id 
FROM user_nices a
INNER JOIN user_nices b
ON a.user_id = b.target_id AND b.user_id = a.target_id
```

And I also have a `users` table where the user information are stored. And I would like also to get their information. I have created a function in modal in which `id` stands for the current user id.

```
public function getMatches($id){
    return \DB::table('user_nices')
            ->join("user_nices as b", function($q){
                $q->on("user_nices.user_id", "=", "b.target_id");
                $q->on("b.user_id", "=", "user_nices.target_id");
            })
            ->get();
}
```

My code for now retrieves data but without the users information and also should only returns the user's match user as well. 
How can I possibly attain it using Laravel's query builder join query?

Comment: Are you trying to join the same table?

Comment: @pr1nc3 Yes. Please see my update using eloquent.

Comment: Why don't you write a User model and it's relationships?

Comment: Create the models, and then you can start saying you are using Eloquent.

Comment: @Amarnasan I'm sorry. I mean query builder. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Guess you still need another `join` with the users table and a `where` clause to restrict to the selected user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs, I have finally do it this way, but if you have better solutions, I'm still open to it.

```
public function getMatchPeople($uid)
{

    return \DB::table('user_nices')
            ->join("user_nices as b", function($q){
                $q->on("user_nices.user_id", "=", "b.target_id");
                $q->on("b.user_id", "=", "user_nices.target_id");
            })
            ->join('users', function($q){
                $q->on('users.id',"=", "user_nices.target_id");
            })
            //to only get users details who likes current user
            ->where("user_nices.user_id", '=', $uid)
            ->where("user_nices.target_id", '!=', $uid)
            ->selectRaw("user_nices.user_id as user_id, users.name as name,
                        user_nices.id as id, users.email as email, users.nickname as nickname ,user_nices.created_at as create_at")
            ->get();
}
```